# Laravel 5 Eloquent Relationships

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5, relationships

I’m having problems when trying to make relations in my models.

I’ve the objects Client and TypeOfClient. A Client has one TypeOfClient so my code is it:

```
class Client extends Model {

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\TypeOfClient', 'type');
    }

}
```

Where "type" is the foreign key in my clients table, referencing TypeOfClient.

The problem is that when I do this:

```
$client = \App\Client::first();
$client->type
```

I get the identifier string instead of the object. My goal is to get the TypeOfClient with something like this:

```
$client->type->name
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. It was solved automatically when I changed the name of the relationship. At first both the name of the column in the database and the relation name was "type". When I changed the name of the column to type_id, $client->type started to return me the TypeOfClient object.

Answer (score 0):

You've identified the issue in your answer, but to summarize...

Any time you have a table with column name, example, `type` and a function/relationship/etc with the same name, in this case, `type`, eloquent will automatically prioritize the column name over the functions.

That is one reason why common conventions of eloquents models will be to append `_id` and use, in this case, `type_id` for foreign key id column names, that way you can use `type` as a relationship without any issues (and it's clear, good practice, etc etc)